# RC 522 RFID Error arduino

Tags: arduino, rfid

I am using the https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid library to connect my Arduino mega to a RFID RC522 but I am having no luck.

> MFRC522 Software Version: 0x0 (unknown) WARNING: Communication
>   failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected? Scan PICC to see UID,
>   type, and data blocks...

I have connected all the pins according to the document.
Any ideas what I could have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt set the pins correctly